# How to get the coloured box characters in a wordle answer file to show up in Notepad?

Tags: notepad

I am using Windows 10. I've installed Clear Sans but when I copy and paste the answer file from a Wordle game into Notepad the squares are showing up as empty black squares, not as full-colour squares as they should.

Rather than

Wordle 322 4/6

⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜⬜
⬜⬜⬜

they look like this:

[image]

Comment: You can't: Notepad is text-only. Copy to a *word processor*, such as LibreOffice *Writer* or MS Office *Word*. MS *Wordpad* might work, or  not.

Comment: Many thanks. But when I copy a Wordle record to clipboard I am not getting it to show in colour when pasting it to any of Notepad, Libre Office Writer (6.3.2.2) (the boxes show up as shaded dark, shaded light, or unshaded), or MS Word (2003) (boxes show up as on Notepad and as above in the question).